# angularjs adding my own function to the existing ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have `ng-click="foo()"` which alert "foo"
In my own directive, if ng-click is found, I want to add another function to alert "bar"

I tried this
DEMO:  http://plnkr.co/edit/1zYl0mSxeLoMU3yjoGBV?p=preview

and it did not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = function() { alert('foo'); }
      $scope.bar = function() { alert('bar'); }
    });
    app.directive("myAttr", function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          el.attr('ng-click', attrs.ngClick+';bar()');
        }
      }
    })
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a my-attr ng-click="foo()" href="">click here!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was also not able to another ng-* directive to this to make it work, i.e. `el.attr('ng-focus', 'bar()');`. It seems that I cannot change or add ng-* directive once it is rendered.

How can I achieve this, and what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Angular needs to compile your expression before it can setup watches and link to your controller function.

Comment: @Chandermani, that's what I thought and added `          el.html($compile(el)(scope));` after el.attr(..), and it makes the browser crashed, assuming loop happens(don't know why)

Comment: Because compiling the directive element again causes link function to be called recursively. Move the element that you want to compile inside the directive and try.

Comment: @Chandermani, I don't get `Move the element that you want to compile inside directive and try`. I don't feel smart enough. I got to sleep then.

Comment: Maybe something like  `<div my-attr><a ng-click="foo()" href="">click here!</a></div>`. You link function would change accordingly.

Comment: What's your use case here? I suspect there might be a more maintainable / cleaner way of adding functionality to a directive than adding functions to the DOM in this way.

Comment: @MichalCharemza, that's good point. I can add a eventListener to the element in directive. If it is not about event, i.e. manipulating the existing directive, this still can happen. But, it might not be a good idea either to manipulate pre-defined directive. It does not seem angular way.

Answer (score 4):

```
  app.directive("myAttr", function() {
  return {
      priority: 1,
      compile: function(el, attrs) {
       attrs.ngClick += ';bar()';
    }
  }
})
```

First of all you want a `compile` function, for when `link` is called, the `ng-click` directive is already set up.

The second important thing is to change the priority. You want to ensure that your directive is called before `ng-click`. `ng-click` has the default priority 0, so 1 is enough.

The last and important thing, which is not obvious, is that you don't want to change the element, but `attrs` itself. It is created only once per element. So when `ng-click` accesses it it would still contain the same value, if you changed the attribute on the element directly.

Comment: this is so hawt. I've been vaguely trying to come up with a use case for priority for a while. Is there any reason why this is better then my solution below?

Comment: @AbrahamP thx :) The big advantage is that it's independent of the existing expression. It doesn't matter if its' `foo()`, `baz()` or whatever. And it changes the expression before anything happens. So basically it's like `bar()` has always been there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you want with `ngTransclude`.

```
app.directive("myAttr", function() {
  return {
    transclude:true,
    template: '<span ng-click="bar()" ng-transclude></span>',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    }
  }
});
```

Does that work?

**EDIT**

Okay what about this one?

```
app.directive("myAttr", function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.attr('ng-click', 'bar()');
      el.removeAttr('my-attr');
      $compile(el)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: works, but bar() happens before foo() happens. it also rely on event bubbling. It's does not feel right.

Comment: I think using `$compile` like that can be inefficient; it might do extra compiling.  I don't know how to use pre- and post- links or whatever.  I think that does what you want, though.

Comment: I think your second method will only execute the `bar()`

Comment: In the browser it did both for me.  It gave me an error when I tried to save/fork the plunkr so you'll have to try yourself.  If it doesn't work for you that's weird.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared yeah you are right... but how come it is still executing foo when that attribute is completely replaced?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because there's an array of event handlers on the DOM element somewhere and recompiling the element just adds to that array - it doesn't empty it.  My first attempt was to just append `;bar()` but when it called `foo` twice I decided to take out the `ng-click` and voila.  So I see why you thought that -- I did, too.

Comment: Thats exactly what happened with me. foo getting executed twice. Interesting theory about handlers array not refreshing properly.

Answer (score 2):

While this could be done with compile as outlined above, that approach doesn't guarantee the order in which the ng-click items would be added to a DOM node (as you have already discovered), and is inherently slow (as has been pointed out by Words Like Jared.

Personally, I would just do something like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
     <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.foo = function() { alert('foo'); }
          $scope.bar = function() { alert('bar'); }
       });

       app.directive('myAttr', function() {
        return {
          scope: true,
          link: function(scope, el, attrs) {  
             if(attrs.hasOwnProperty('ngClick')){
                scope.foo = function(){
                   scope.$parent.foo();
                   scope.$parent.bar();
                }  
             }
          }
        };
      });
     </script>
   </head>

    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <a my-attr ng-click="foo()" href="">click here!</a>
    </body>

   </html>
```

Whats going on:

`scope: true`: By default directives do not create new scopes, simply sharing their parent scope. By setting `scope: true`, every instance of this directive will create a child scope, that will prototypically inherit from the parent scope.

Then you can simply override the method desired (`foo()`) and voila

Live demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8A8y96wAhqGEowFaRQUH?p=preview

Comment: And if the function isn't named foo? Or if `ng-click` contains a more complex expression? And what's the point of using `hasOwnProperty` in this case (I'm just curious)?

Answer (score 0):

I freely admit I may entirely misunderstand what you are trying to do. However, given the example you provided, I think you might be better served by separating concerns a little more.

It seems from your example that you are trying to trigger `foo` and `bar` together whenever your directive is present. If both `foo` and `bar` are concerns of the controller, then why not wrap them both up in another function and assign that function to the `ng-click` of your element. If `foo` is a concern of the controller, but `bar` is a concern of the directive, why not trigger the `bar` functionality directly from the directive code?

**If the functionality wrapped up in 'foo' *and* 'bar' is suppose to be defined by the controller creator...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = function() { alert('foo'); }
      $scope.bar = function() { alert('bar'); }
      $scope.pak = function() {
        $scope.foo();
        $scope.bar();
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a ng-click="pak()" href="">click here!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Or, if the functionality wrapped up in 'foo' is suppose to be defined by the controller creator, but the functionality wrapped up in 'bar' is suppose to be defined by the directive creator...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = function() { alert('foo'); }
    });
    app.directive('myAttr', function(){
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.click(function(){
            alert('bar');
          });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a ng-click="foo()" href="">click here!</a>
</body>
</html>
```